# Can OpenStack Compute be used to process images as a back-end on cloud for a front-end Android App?

Tags: android, cloud, openstack, devstack

OpenStack compute is a platform that can use the clouds resources for computation. I want to perform image analysis in an android app but I want the computation to happen on back-end i.e. OpenStack Cloud. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack elastic compute, also known as nova, is basically an API interface to a python framework that automates Hypervisor provisioning and software defined networking.

As a result, an elastic instance in openstack is virtually indistinguishable from a virtual machine.

So as far as your android app is concerned, tying into openstack instances is the same as polling a remote server, or servers.

I don't know what sort of image analysis you are doing, what software you rely on.  But you would need your analysis to be able to occur remotely.  And be remotely kicked off by the android app.  Probably through some sort of API.  Depending on the complexity of your work you may need to build load balancers or command and control systems for distributed computing schedulers and the like.

It's hard to say what you will have to do to achieve your ends knowing so little about what your ends are.